# Regex differentiate between first and street c# regex.replace

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following data:

```
123ST
89ST
101ST
1ST
TEST
```

I would like to differentiate between first and street and then place a space if it does not contain a 1 as the last character.

```
Add Space:

123 ST
89 ST

Do not modify:

101ST
1ST
TEST
```

Here is what I have so far but have not found a solution:

```
address = Regex.Replace(address, @"\sST", " ");
```

NOTES: Non-numeric data should not be modified as seen in the TEST example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
address = Regex.Replace(address, @"(?<=[02-9])ST$", " $&");
// Or, if `ST` appears in the start/middle of the string and is at the end of a "word"
address = Regex.Replace(address, @"(?<=[02-9])ST\b", " $&");
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5b02-9%5d%29ST%5cb&i=123ST%0d%0a89ST%0d%0a101ST%0d%0a1ST%0d%0aTEST&r=+%24%26).

The regex matches

- `(?<=[02-9])` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a `0` digit, or a digit from `2` to `9` range
- `ST`  - an `ST` substring
- `$` - end of string and
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: Hi Wiktor thank you.  Sorry forgot to mention about non-numeric should not be modified.  I updated the items to include the word TEST.

Comment: @RobertSmith So, you want to match `ST` only after a non-`1` digit, right?

Comment: Hi Wiktor thank you it worked!  Yes only match 2-9 and zero.  Great job.